# Alamofire with -u

Tags: ios, swift, curl, alamofire, omise

I need to make this request in Alamofire.

```
curl https://api.omise.co/charges \
  -u $OMISE_SECRET_KEY: \
  -d "amount=100000" \
  -d "currency=thb" \
  -d "card=tokn_test_5g5mep9yrko3vx2f0hx"
```

I guess it should be something like

```
let url = "https://api.omise.co/charges"
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["amount": 100000,
                                  "currency": "thb",
                                  "card": token]
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success( _):
            let data = responseJSON.result.value!
            print(data)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)

     }
}
```

How do I make a request?

I don't know how to handle `-u $ OMISE_SECRET_KEY:`.

Comment: It looks like `-u` is trying to use basic auth. https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+https%3A%2F%2Fapi.omise.co%2Fcharges+%5C+++-u+%24OMISE_SECRET_KEY%3A+%5C+++-d+%22amount%3D100000%22+%5C+++-d+%22currency%3Dthb%22+%5C+++-d+%22card%3Dtokn_test_5g5mep9yrko3vx2f0hx%22 Read the docs: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#http-basic-authentication

Comment: I didn't understand when I read the document.
Where should I add the secret key?

Comment: You should aim to fully understand what the cURL command is doing before you try to "translate" it. `-u some_username:some_password` is the cURL syntax for expressing [HTTP basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). In your case, the username is the value of the `OMISE_SECRET_KEY` variable, and there is no password (hence the `:` with nothing after it). So you need `.authenticate(username: omiseSecretKey, password: nil)` (or perhaps `""` instead of nil`)